# Reasoning about and finding the top most "parent" prototype object of a class instance?

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop, prototype

Good day.

I'm taking a JS course and right now we're covering Prototypes. My question has to do with the prototype object.

Here's the code sample:

```
class Pet {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    eat() {
        return `${this.name} is eating!`
    }
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    bark() {
        return "Woof!"
    }
    eat() {
        return `${this.name} scarfs his food!` 
    }
}

const wyatt = new Dog("Wyatt", 13);
```

If I type in the console:
`wyatt.eat()`

(1) The console will look for the eat method on the Dog prototype. If it finds it, it'll run the method.

(2) If it doesn't find it there it will look at the Pet prototype for it, courtesy of the extends keyword.

(3) Now if it doesn't find it there, the console will look for it on the "Object Prototype" (the way the tutor formulated it).

I get all of the above and that a class instance has a prototype template it refers to, and possibly others. The confusing part for me is specifically at step (3), what is the prototype here? Is it looking on the global object? Would that be the window object? This part is still a bit shaky for me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While what you wrote is not wrong, the realty is simpler (IMO).

If you try to access a property on an object, the engine will first check whether the object itself (in your case `wyatt`) has that property. If not, it will look at the object's prototype (which is also an object) and repeat those steps until it finds the property or until an object doesn't have a prototype anymore. That's really all that is to it.

An object can only have one prototype. You can think of it as it being an "internal" property that is assigned a reference to another object.

I guess the next question is, how is a prototype assigned to an object? You already know one way: the `extends` keyword.
Maybe the point that you are missing is that the *default prototype* of an object is `Object.prototype`:

```js
console.log(Object.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf({}));
```

`Object.prototype` however doesn't have a prototype:

```js
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype));
```

That's where the prototype chain ends.

---

So to summarize, the engine doesn't think "oh I have to look at `Object.prototype` now", it just knows to look at the object's prototype, whatever that may be. It's just the case that `Object.prototype` is the default prototype for "normal" objects.